# Adhan when it causes a disturbance to local non-muslim majority

Tags: prayer-timings, non-muslim-countries

Currently, in the UK (and perhaps other places where non-muslims are a majority) there is a debate as to whether Adhan should be recited on a loudspeaker if it could cause aggravation to the local non-muslim population.

In such a situation could a call to prayer (on a loudspeaker) be justified if it causes disturbance i.e. is it an obligation no matter what the scenario, or merely something that is preferable under the correct circumstances?

Comment: A loudspeaker is not necessary to call for the prayer!

Comment: @Medi1Saif regardless, my question addresses the current debate that some communities feel they have a right to have the Adhan on a loudspeaker, despite it causing a disturbance to the general public. Is this still allowed?

Comment: In Sweden the adhan is only done loud in the mosque, and not outside. And that is OK, especially because it's a non-muslim country.

Comment: @Medi1Saif are you therefore suggesting it should never be done on loudspeaker because it will inevitably cause a disturbance?

Comment: @bondonk yes and I'm against loudspeakers who are set in a mosque and can be heard outside. One ramadan I was praying outside a mosque in my homeland and had problems to follow my Imam because there I could hear the prayer from three different mosques as all of them had set their loudspeakers to a very loud level. I mean even if it is a Muslim country some people want or need to work Allah didn't ask as to disturb others to pray. Even those people who during a prayer set your (by moving it) or their feet are a disturbance that is makrooh!

Answer (score 0):

a loud speaker is not necessary for Adhan. We know that Ibrahim(a.s) was ordered to recite the Adhan and Allah made his voice travel the world. hence we may build a faith that even without the loud speaker, Allah is all able to get the people(who wish tio come for prayer) to hear that. for Allah is the most powerfull, and most able.

Comment: is "his voice travel the world" metaphorical or it made a physical sound across the world? Also, please can you bring a source for your answer

Comment: Are you also suggesting that it should never be done with a loudspeaker since it inevitably causes a disturbance?